# How to find the space used by a number of rows in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to find out how much space certain rows are taking up in multiple tables. I will then add them together and show users how much space they are using in the SQL database.

Using the `sp_spaceused` stored procedure gets me details about the table as a whole but I need to find the space used on a filtered number of records.

Is there any way to add a WHERE conditon to the `sp_spaceused` procedure so I can get details about a set of rows in the table, or is there another solution?

Comment: This should help .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187445.aspx

Comment: This sheet will give you an idea how to use the formulas given above: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20154

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30683141/4519059)? ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the average space taken by row and then can calculate the space required by 'n' no. of rows i.e. You can use `sp_spaceused` to get total footprint/rowcount = avg space per row.